# Film about a guy who wakes up to messages on the inside of his window, multiple times, when no one else is living there

Tags: story-identification, movie

He initially wipes the messages off but then decides to try and work out what is going on by going to some of the places that the messages say - one mentions a girl and an alleyway but of course he doesn't know which one. He, at one point, is being followed by a shadowy figure that turns out to be the dad of the girl that the guy is trying to help/he makes friends with. We eventually find out that his future self is essentially taking control of his past self whilst he's sleeping to write these messages, though I don't think he's always in control of it.

I think it was made within the last ten years and probably a lower-budget film. There are more scenes I remember but I think I'm mixing films up so I don't want to confuse things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [***Chronesthesia***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5729870/) (2016)

> Daniel Duncombe is not a committer. When he’s not working at a café or
> running to stay in shape, he’s perfectly happy to chill at home. Then
> he starts waking up from weird dreams to find cryptic messages
> scrawled on his bedroom window. Slowly it dawns on Daniel that the
> same mysterious force is guiding him into contact with a strange
> assortment of equally unattached strangers who intrude on his routine.
>
> <sub><sup><sub><sup>[Letterboxd](https://letterboxd.com/film/chronesthesia/)</sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: That's the one. Thank you so much for understanding my vague description and saving me from going crazy!

Comment: @anon18 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM